# Module is not properly working on live server in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I have created one module and it is working properly in my local server(windows),but when i put it on live server(linux) it is not working properly.Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Assign/apply  proper permission and check, lot of times this could be caused by file/folder permissions.

Comment: @Krish at i95Dev you mean the folder permission of that module and files?

Comment: @Krish at i95Dev : I have checked all the folder permissions and it have read write permissions.

Comment: Please provide the folder structure and naming conventions, The most common problems are associated with case sensitivity. If you have Windows hosting, then the error in the uppercase/lowercase characters is not visible and it works. But as soon as it gets to linux hosting, the module will not work.

Comment: @Krish at i95Dev: app->code->Aufy->Pincode this is my folder structure of that module

Comment: Fine, Please check with php bin/magento module:status whether your module is listed.

Comment: Yes the status is enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68060/discussion-between-krish-at-i95dev-and-christy).